# Truncate ALL tables procedure running but not working properly on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, truncate

I'm making a procedure for truncate ALL tables in MySQL, but i don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE TRUNC_TEST1()

BEGIN


SELECT Concat(EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ',table_schema,'.`',TABLE_NAME, '`;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where  table_schema in ('*my_database_name*');

END
// DELIMITER ;
```

What I get while running the procedure is a result grid with all the TRUNCATE TABLE ..database.tablename.., but at the time of running a SELECT query, table is not empty, so it's not working properly

If I use a "`TRUNCATE TABLE database.tablename"` instead of the `"SELECT CONCAT....."`, it works
Is there an easy way or something to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Why bother, back up ddl , drop database, load backup. NB haven't tested this...

Comment: @P.Salmon Why would I drop an entire database every time I want to do a truncate?

Comment: BTW your approach may be incorrect if you have foreign keys to deal with.

Comment: 'Why would I drop an entire database every time I want to do a truncate?; - what;s real the difference here you are truncating all tables after all..just a choice of what is quicker and easier..

Comment: @P.Salmon "what;s real the difference here you are truncating all tables after all..just a choice of what is quicker and easier.." - I want to make it faster with a truncate, I need to make a function to call it when need it and I think that's easier...

Comment: Ok in that case you need to create prepared statements for every table to be truncated making sure that you truncate tables with foreign keys before you delete the referenced tables see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html nb dynamic sql can only execute 1 statement at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use below procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE truncate_table(in my_schema varchar(55))
BEGIN 

    SELECT Concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME ,';' ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'world_x';

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

If a call it with:

```
call truncate_table('world_x');
```

It will return:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME ,';' ) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| TRUNCATE TABLE city;                        |
| TRUNCATE TABLE country;                     |
| TRUNCATE TABLE countryinfo;                 |
| TRUNCATE TABLE countrylanguage;             |
+---------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can copy this result and use it on your command line, but before executing  you need to log into MySQL and disable Foreign Key checks before truncating tables, using the following command

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

After you truncate tables, re-enable foreign key checks

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```